# $E(XY)$ for a truncated bivariate normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, numerical-integration

If $(X, Y)$ follows a bivariate Gaussian distribution with mean ${\bf \mu}$ and covariance ${\bf \Sigma}$ with truncation bounds $(a_x, b_x, a_y, b_y)$, can we compute $E(XY)$ in closed form? If not, can we compute/estimate it quickly and efficiently?

For context, I need to do thousands (or more) of these integrals and so I'd like to be able to compute these faster than via (say) Monte Carlo.

Comment: This is done numerically but can be efficient.  Google `mvtnorm`.

Comment: @whuber I am familiar with the `mvtnorm` R package, if that's what you're referring to. But it does not seem that there are any tools for my particular problem -- unless you're suggesting Monte Carlo, which I am hoping to avoid/improve on.

Comment: How about numerical integration via a Gauss-Legendre quadrature rule?

Comment: `mvtnorm` computes the denominators and the numerator can be integrated into a closed form in one dimension, leaving an ordinary (univariate) integral to compute (supporting @JarleTufto's claim).  If there are relationships among these integrals -- for instance, if they use the same distribution but differ only by region of integration -- then substantial speedups are possible. Another example would be if all the integrals have the same correlation, because you could tabulate all possibilities beforehand (they depend only on two parameters) and interpolate in your table.